# discord.py dming/pinging random members in a server as a chat revive system

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Is there a way I can dm or ping random members in a server to revive chat? I don't know if dming random people in a server will flag the bot but just in case perhaps I can ping in a channel? If so, How can I make it pick a certain amount of random members in a server? For example 5 random members in a server.

```
@client.hybrid_command(name="Chat Revive",with_app_command=True,descriptrion="Revive Chat",aliases=["revive", "dead chat"])
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.is_owner()
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = 1009907559391567912))
async def Chat Revive(ctx):
    dm = True
    while True:
        for members in ctx.guild.members:
            member = random.choice(members)
            await member.send("Chat Revive! Talk in <#1009907560624685148> and gain perks and levels in the server!")
```

I have this so far and and the only error I get is `object of type 'Member' has no len()`

Please help

Comment: Perhaps you'd rather choose a random element of `ctx.guild.members`. Iterating over each single member, and then choosing a random single member, does not at first blush appear sensible.

Comment: @J_H I figured it out, I used random.sample in the random library

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines:

```py
for members in ctx.guild.members:
    member = random.choice(members)
```

to the following:

```py
member = random.choice(ctx.guild.members)
```

Also remember to `import random`